.NET Framework Config Builders v3 - How do I make SectionHandler<T> for complex objects?
I am trying my best to grok the SectionHandler documentation for MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders. I am already successfully using the UserSecretsConfigBuilder and replacing tokens that look like ${...} in my appSettings and connectionStrings blocks in my web.config file.
Now I want to use this for a more complex ConfigurationSection object that might look like this in my web.config file:
<specialSection>
    <configs>
        <configThatGetsOverwritten 
            name="key" 
            tokenizedValueOne="${tokenizedValueOne}"
            tokenizedValueTwo="${tokenizedValueTwo}" 
            tokenizedValueThree="${tokenizedValueThree}" />
    </configs>
</specialSection>

I am trying to create a SectionHandler object for this, but it appears that it can only handle one tokenized setting per block--not three, as in my example.  Is that correct?
Here's the code I've tried so far:
public class SpecialSectionSectionHandler : SectionHandler<SpecialSectionConfiguration>
{        
    public override IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, object>> KeysValuesAndState()
    {
        ConfigThatGetsOverwrittenElement[] configThatGetsOverwrittenSettings = new ConfigThatGetsOverwrittenElement[ConfigSection.SpecialSectionConfiguration.Configs.Count];
        ConfigSection.SpecialSectionConfiguration.Configs.CopyTo(configThatGetsOverwrittenSettings, 0);

        foreach (ConfigThatGetsOverwrittenElement setting in configThatGetsOverwrittenSettings)
            yield return Tuple.Create(setting.Name, setting.TokenizedValueOne, (object)setting);
    }

    public override void InsertOrUpdate(string newKey, string newValue, string oldKey = null, object oldItem = null) 
    {
        if (newValue != null)
        {

            ConfigThatGetsOverwrittenElement cs = (oldItem as ConfigThatGetsOverwrittenElement) ?? new ConfigThatGetsOverwrittenElement();
            ConfigSection.SpecialSectionConfiguration.Configs.Remove(oldKey);
            ConfigSection.SpecialSectionConfiguration.Configs.Remove(newKey);

            cs.Name = newKey;
            cs.TokenizedValueOne = newValue;

            ConfigSection.SpecialSectionConfiguration.Configs.Add(cs);
        }
    }
}

This works well enough, but it only handles tokenizedValueOne and not the other two.  How do I make sure it tokenizes all three?
